# dynamic SQL adding base on above row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate Col A,  Col B, Col C from my database SQL Server... I want to dynamically populate Col C base on the row above it Col C = ( Col A + Col B + Col C [Above] )... I draw an example incase my explanations wasnt clear enough

[image]

Please Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this for different approaches for running total http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals